# "Rightarrow" in TikzPicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I have this code:

```
 \begin{tikzcd}[arrows = Rightarrow]
      metrico    
      \arrow[r,"(5)"]  
      \arrow[rrr,bend right,"(1)"]
      & \mathrm{T4} \arrow[r,"(4)"]
      & \mathrm{T3} \arrow[r,"(3)"]
      & \mathrm{T2} \arrow[r,"(2)"] 
      & \mathrm{T1}
 \end{tikzcd}
```

And this output:

[image]

There is a way to have this output instead?

[image]

Comment: You'll get better and faster answers if you turn this into a minimal working example that goes from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.  It takes a bit of time on your end (but not much) and saves everyone else that much time.

Comment: Yes, there is...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `to path` argument to specify the path taken.  To place the label you need to add a node to the appropriate point on the `to path` and give it the standard label styling.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows = Rightarrow]
      \mathrm{metrico}
      \arrow[r,"(5)"]
      \arrow[rrr,to path={  -- +(0,-4ex) -| node[pos=0.25,commutative
      diagrams/every label]{$(1)$}
      (\tikztotarget)}]
      & \mathrm{T4} \arrow[r,"(4)"]
      & \mathrm{T3} \arrow[r,"(3)"]
      & \mathrm{T2} \arrow[r,"(2)"]
      & \mathrm{T1}
 \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `to path` is built of two paths, the second with `-|` is a segment with the bend positioned at `pos=0.5`, so `pos=0.25` is what is needed to get the middle of the long segment.

Also your word `metrico` is being typeset in mathematics, so gets poor spacing of the letters.  I have adjusted it by putting the word inside `\mathrm`.

Comment: `anchor=north` will put the number below the arrow.

Comment: @Bobyandbob ...or a simple `swap` option.